# I accidentally set my default terminal command to "killall Terminal"

Tags: macos, terminal

It wasn't just killall Terminal. It was `some command;killall Terminal` because all I wanted to do was run an sshfs command and then exit the terminal, and previously using `some command;exit` had yielded un-satisfactory results, with me forgetting to quit Terminal and such. But now, the command is exiting with an error and I can't open the preferences or open my default terminal window because it automatically exits every time. Is there any way to restore Terminal to it's original settings? I feel really stuptid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that going to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` and using a 3rd party editor called [pref setter](http://www.nightproductions.net/prefsetter.html) to edit the startup key to take the command away.